# PHP SQL query password must be equal to column name to be valid, not the actual value?

Tags: php, html, sql, mamp

I have a somewhat strange problem that I don't really know why it's happening.
First off, I'm try to access a database using php which is working out fine. It can access it without fail (checked) so I'm pretty sure that area of it is correct.

I'm accessing the query with the php code:

```
mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $username AND password =     $password");
```

It's accessing the database:

[image: The Database Definition]

So here's the problem. I'm trying to login with a username and password. If I put in the wrong username, it picks it up and rejects it, so theres nothing wrong with the username part. However if I use the right username and password, it still rejects it because of the password. But if I use the right username and the password 'password' (the same as the column name, I've tried it with different column names with the same effect) it works, as long as the username is correct.

Previously I used echo's to make sure both the user and passwords I typed in was being received and they are.

Comment: SQL injection warning: put quotes around `$username` and `$password` and use `mysqli_real_escape_string` (or better: use parameterized queries). And it's considered bad practice to store passwords in plain text; use PHP's `crypt` function to encrypt passwords.

Comment: +1 for including all the detail required to quickly diagnose your problem. Well asked.

Comment: I'd suggest using PDO and named parameters, rather than mysqli_query and concatenating strings. I automatically prevents any SQL injection, and is clearer to write.  And simpler than mysqli_* fns.

Comment: Thanks, never knew that part, assumed it wouldn't applied to due php syntax, thanks! i'll try that string warning from now on hehe

Comment: if you are still no using `mysql_real_escape_string` etc or `PDO` then pass `correctUsername' or '1=1` to your username field and whatever in password. it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $username AND password = $password");`

to:

`mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");`

ie put quotes around your strings.

You're probably actually getting an error back from the database... so you should also check for that too.

**EDIT:** Also please take note of @MarcelKorpel's comment/warning about SQL Injection.  My solution above corrects your syntax error.  Marcel's warning corrects the error in your approach ;-)  The point is that if the `$username` or `$password` strings are not sanitised, SQL code can be (eg) typed in by an end-user, effectively changing your query string to something unintended (by you) that might be (probably will be) malicious.

Comment: @CailDemetri My pleasure mate.  I noticed you've got a few questions pending an accept (including this one...:-).  When you get a chance would you mind returning the love with a big green tick?